# Using Apache Directory Studio

Tags: apache, sockets, ldap

I have followed http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Creating+a+Connection+to+your+LDAP+Directory
for basic understanding and trying to set up LDAP for my office use.

scenario:
I have started `Apache 2.2` (Apache Directory Server) at localhost:389 and it's running fine.

Next, I installed  `Apache Directory`Studio and trying to create new connection. But I am getting the following error while opening the connection:

```
Error while opening connection - localhost:389; socket closed  
  javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: localhost:389; socket closed  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(Unknown Source)  
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.reconnect(Unknown Source)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$7.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1055)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1272)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.doBind(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1065)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.bind(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:254)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.OpenConnectionsRunnable.run(OpenConnectionsRunnable.java:114)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.StudioConnectionJob.run(StudioConnectionJob.java:114)  
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Please guide me!
I resolved this by changing the`port numbers.` 
Now I am getting the following error:

```
Error while opening connection - [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]  
  javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)    
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)    
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(Unknown Source)  
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.reconnect(Unknown Source)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$7.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1055)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1272)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.doBind(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1065)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.bind(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:254)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.OpenConnectionsRunnable.run(OpenConnectionsRunnable.java:114)  
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.StudioConnectionJob.run(StudioConnectionJob.java:114)  
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your connection to the ldap server is wrong. I know the default username and password for Apache DS is admin and secret respectively.

Try the following as the bind DN or user string:

```
uid=admin,ou=system
```